# how to Remove Escaping character ( Back slash "\") from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has escaping characters back slash - () . I would like to remove all the escaping characters from the data frame.

Is there any smart way in python to remove escape characters and clean up the dataframe.

I tried the below code

```
df['name']= df['name'].str.encode('utf-8').str.decode('unicode_escape')
```

this gives me a error like below

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 20-21: malformed \N character escape
```

My sample df

```
name
ALTRAN CONSULTING & \NENGINEERING GMBH
NANOVO KERESKEDELMI KFT \KENYSZERTORLES ALATT
SCHLUESSELBAUER \TECHNOLOGY GMBH & CO KG
HIMOLLA \SERVICE GMBH
LINDAL \VENTIL GMBH
CBB \ALTALANOS IPARI SZOLGALTATO BT
FRIEB BUMAG \VERTRIEBS GMBH
FATIMEX TECHNOLOGIES KFT \VEGELSZAMOLAS ALATT \" \"FELSZAMOLAS ALATT
BACSKA \AGRAR IPARI ZARTKORUEN MUKODO RT
SAG DEUTSCHLAND GMBH\N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) -

```
>>> import pandas as pd                                                                               
>>> 
>>> val = [r"ALTRAN CONSULTING & \NENGINEERING GMBH",r"NANOVO KERESKEDELMI KFT \KENYSZERTORLES ALATT"]
>>> 
>>> d = {'name':val}                                                                               
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df['name'] = df['name'].replace(to_replace= r'\\', value= '', regex=True)
>>> df
                                           name
0         ALTRAN CONSULTING & NENGINEERING GMBH
1  NANOVO KERESKEDELMI KFT KENYSZERTORLES ALATT
>>>
```