# How to escape special characters in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I pulled a report from a crm system that came with some special characters like:

```
Belgium&#x20;&#x28;Dutch&#x29;                                
Saint&#x20;Lucia                                              
Trinidad&#x20;and&#x20;Tobago                                 
Sierra&#x20;Leone                                             
Mali                                                          
Svalbard&#x20;and&#x20;Jan&#x20;Mayen
```

This is a drop down menu from the web interface that contains all the countries and regions. Per what I read this is an xml formatting issue. I am processing this in Python Pandas. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866181/how-to-remove-escaping-character-back-slash-from-pandas-dataframe) post I got an idea but I'd like to write a regex to escape any string with similar sequence of characters.

By the way, I imported the csv file like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('report.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

And use this to try to escape the characters (which worked for that case only):

```
df['Country/Region'] = df['Country/Region'].replace(to_replace='&#x28;', value= ' ', regex=False)
```

This is to a specific character. But I could not figure out with a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
import html
df['Country/Region'] = df['Country/Region'].astype(str).map(html.unescape)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Country/Region
0         Belgium (Dutch)
1             Saint Lucia
2     Trinidad and Tobago
3            Sierra Leone
4                    Mali
5  Svalbard and Jan Mayen
```

Comment: I am getting this error (but I am sure everything is a string):
 --> 130     if '&' not in s:
    131         return s
    132     return _charref.sub(_replace_charref, s)

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: Hmm...well, I guess everything isn't! :) Check the update now, @rbrt.